# Turn VideoHeader into Image when responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using a JS Plugin I found on GitHub that makes a video header parallax, the problem is that when I run it responsive for phone the video turns black, im trying to change the video for an image when responsive mode.

I tried with @mediatag but can't make it work.

```
<main style="height: 100%">
        <video class="bv-video"></video>
 </main>

<script>
    const backgroundVideo = new BackgroundVideo('.bv-video', {
        src: [
            'img/01.mp4',
            'img/01.mp4'
        ],
        onReady: function() {
            // Use onReady() to prevent flickers or force loading state
            const vidParent = document.querySelector(`.${this.bvVideoWrapClass}`);
            vidParent.classList.add('bv-video-wrap--ready');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Link for the plugin - Licensed under the MIT license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using media queries, its simple.

All you would need to do is write a media query in your css to display your image at a maximum screen width and display none for your video. Also set the image display to none outside of the media query so it defaults to that until the media query detects the mobile screen width and changes it.